# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'client' of undefined or null reference

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, iis, signalr

There are several similar questions but none of the answers seem to work.
I have 3 different web sites (one page each) built using Visual Studio Express 2013 Web.
They all use signalR. In fact one is the example SignalR.Sample that can be downloaded from Nuget.
They all work on IIS Express.
They all USED to work on IIS.
They all give the above error on IIS  using Internet Explorer set to debug. FireFox and Chrome just give the webpage without starting signalR.
The exact same 3 sites work on IIS on a separate computer.

So I think it is my setup of IIS that has changed and is wrong.

Previous to the problem I had loaded Abyss Web Server to try to get the site running on that (I failed) and I had deselected IIS so that it could not possibly be interfering.

I have now removed Abyss and reinstated IIS making sure that ASP.Net and  .Net 4 is being used.

Can anybody direct me where to look for the problem?

Just for the record I show below the jQuery files being loaded

```
 <!--Script references. -->
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the jQuery.color library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js"></script>
<!--Reference jonson2 for old Browsers script. -->
<script src="Scripts/json2.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
<!--Reference the StockTicker script. -->
<script src="APRS.js"></script>
<!--Reference the sorting jquery script. -->
<script src="sorttable.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you try to get 'signalr/hubs' directly from the browser, what do you get? Can you find your hub's proxy definition there?

Comment: The thing now works! I ran a program called Reimage Repair which is supposed to clean up your Windows system. I normally ignore it's pleas to do something because it takes too long but today I let it run and Hey Presto iis7 does as it should.